# Is there a way to filter Google places restaurants by opening hours?

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

Ionic 3 - Is there a way to filter Google places restaurants by opening hours to filter by open_now or rating?

```js
getTypes(latLng) {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Procurando...'
    });

loading.present();

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
let request = {
  location: latLng,
  radius: this.isKM,
  type: [this.item]
};
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    service.nearbySearch(request, function (results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        resolve(results);
        loading.dismiss();
      } else {
         loading.dismiss();
         reject(status);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`nearbySearch()` in the PlacesService does have an `openNow` option to only search for places that are open at the time that your query is sent. So your sample code modified would be:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
let request = {
  location: latLng,
  radius: this.isKM,
  type: [this.item],
  openNow: true
};
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    service.nearbySearch(request, function (results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        resolve(results);
        loading.dismiss();
      } else {
         loading.dismiss();
         reject(status);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

[Nearby Search Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)